# I cannot save /etc/sysctl.conf in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I want to disable IPv6 on my Ubuntu 12.04 but when added following line in "/etc/sysctl.conf" and try to save, it giving me error "Could not create a backup file while saving /etc/sysctl.conf"

```
# disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the command you are using to open the /etc/sysctl.conf file? Probably is "sudo gedit", right?

Try:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

or

```
sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf
```